# Extracting string from Substring in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I have a line like this:

```xml
<option value="bo">Tibetan Standard, Tibetan, Central</option>
```

I want an output like this:

```
bo Tibetan Standard, Tibetan, Central
```

When I am trying to do with `sed`:

```bash
sed -r 's/.*value="(\S+).*">(\S+)<.*/\1 \2/'
```

It gives only:

```
bo Tibetan
```

Can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance

Comment: <option value="bo">Tibetan Standard, Tibetan, Central</option>
the line is like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following modification to your original `sed` should work:

```
sed -r 's_.*value="(.*)">(.*)</option>_\1 \2_'
```

The following example:

```
sed -r 's_.*value="(.*)">(.*)</option>_\1 \2_' <<< '<option value="bo">Tibetan Standard, Tibetan, Central</option>'
```

Prints the desired output:

```
bo Tibetan Standard, Tibetan, Central
```